# vim-go can not find correct GOPATH

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin

When I install vim-go under sudo user in Vim

```
:GoInstallBinaries
```

It report errors:

```
vim-go: gogetdoc not found. Installing github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc: go build github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc: open /usr/local/go/bin/gogetdoc: permission denied^@
vim-go: guru not found. Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: go build golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: open /usr/local/go/bin/guru: permission denied^@
vim-go: golint not found. Installing golang.org/x/lint/golint to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing golang.org/x/lint/golint: go build golang.org/x/lint/golint: open /usr/local/go/bin/golint: permission denied^@
vim-go: fillstruct not found. Installing github.com/davidrjenni/reftools/cmd/fillstruct to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/davidrjenni/reftools/cmd/fillstruct: go build github.com/davidrjenni/reftools/cmd/fillstruct: open /usr/local/go/bin/fillstruct: permission d
enied^@
vim-go: godef not found. Installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef: go build github.com/rogpeppe/godef: open /usr/local/go/bin/godef: permission denied^@
vim-go: motion not found. Installing github.com/fatih/motion to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/fatih/motion: go build github.com/fatih/motion: open /usr/local/go/bin/motion: permission denied^@
vim-go: errcheck not found. Installing github.com/kisielk/errcheck to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/kisielk/errcheck: go build github.com/kisielk/errcheck: open /usr/local/go/bin/errcheck: permission denied^@
vim-go: dlv not found. Installing github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error downloading github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: github.com/derekparker/delve (download)^@# cd /home/fred/go/src/github.com/derekparker/delve; git pull --ff-only^
@error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied^@^@package github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: exit status 1^@
Error installing github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: go build github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv: open /usr/local/go/bin/dlv: permission denied^@
vim-go: gocode not found. Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode: go build github.com/mdempsky/gocode: open /usr/local/go/bin/gocode: permission denied^@
vim-go: impl not found. Installing github.com/josharian/impl to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/josharian/impl: go build github.com/josharian/impl: open /usr/local/go/bin/impl: permission denied^@
vim-go: iferr not found. Installing github.com/koron/iferr to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/koron/iferr: go build github.com/koron/iferr: open /usr/local/go/bin/iferr: permission denied^@
vim-go: gotags not found. Installing github.com/jstemmer/gotags to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/jstemmer/gotags: go build github.com/jstemmer/gotags: open /usr/local/go/bin/gotags: permission denied^@
vim-go: gorename not found. Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: go build golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: open /usr/local/go/bin/gorename: permission denied^@
vim-go: goimports not found. Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports: go build golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports: open /usr/local/go/bin/goimports: permission denied^@
vim-go: gocode-gomod not found. Installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode: go build github.com/stamblerre/gocode: open /usr/local/go/bin/gocode-gomod: permission denied^@
vim-go: gomodifytags not found. Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags: go build github.com/fatih/gomodifytags: open /usr/local/go/bin/gomodifytags: permission denied^@
vim-go: keyify not found. Installing honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/keyify to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/keyify: go build honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/keyify: open /usr/local/go/bin/keyify: permission denied^@
vim-go: asmfmt not found. Installing github.com/klauspost/asmfmt/cmd/asmfmt to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/klauspost/asmfmt/cmd/asmfmt: go build github.com/klauspost/asmfmt/cmd/asmfmt: open /usr/local/go/bin/asmfmt: permission denied^@
vim-go: gometalinter not found. Installing github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter to folder /usr/local/go/bin
Error installing github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter: go build github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter: open /usr/local/go/bin/gometalinter: permission denied^@
vim-go: installing finished!
```

and $GOPATH is:

```
/home/fred/go:/home/fred/folder1:/home/fred/folder2
```

Why vim-go install binaries to

> /usr/local/go/bin
>   # sudo user permisson denied.

not the first path in $GOPATH:

> /home/fred/go

Comment: Unless you ran sudo with the -E option, the GOPATH environment variable was not passed to the executed command.  You can try using the sudo -E flag to fix the problem, but it's probably better to not use sudo at all.

Comment: Is your GOPATH env variable exported ? Can you run `env | grep GOPATH` to verify if it shows any output ? Does the `:GoPath` command within vim show what you expect ?

Comment: I can print value of GOPATH by `:GoPath` in vim.

Comment: I know the way how to pass $GOPATH from myuser to root. `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv`, and problem is not the root can not get gopath, is myuser have no permisson access some system folder and Seemingly I can not use sudo in vim command line. iIt's not convenient to use sudo in some situation but always has no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem.

I set the `go_bin_path` as below in ~./vimrc to fix this

`let g:go_bin_path = $HOME."/go/bin"`

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo chown $LOGNAME /usr/local/go/bin
```

And try again

That will fix the permissions

Comment: This is the sledgehammer approach. Don't do it, normal users shouldn't own stuff in that location.

Comment: Actually, it's /usr/local, it's my laptop, I am the normal user why would I need root privs?  root means the owner of / not /usr/local.  Sorry @nos I can't agree

Comment: The root user is  normally the default owner of / , /usr/ /usr/local /etc. and other places in the filesystem hierarchy. Once you start messing with the default ownerships within these standard directories, you' can easily create a mess.

Comment: /usr/local is traditionally controlled by the local machine and so it's fine to change the permissions to whatever you want.  The bad assumption is to assume that /usr/local will have perms and layout that matches some kind of "standard" because there is none.  If you want to do it "properly" then make the software into a package, put it through acceptance and add it to your system with all the correct paths.  For stuff in /usr/local that is under development IT DOESNT MATTER.